# SSRS Select Distinct on a single column in a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I currently have a view (with a large and complicated join structure) that pulls in a lot of data into a report SSRS. Right now for certain reports there is a duplicate row for each record that flows through to the report rendering it useless. I noticed it does this for some reports and not all of them which really boggles my mind because if there was an error in the base query they all should have duplicate errors.. Anyway I tried to looking into why at the base view but couldn't figure anything out.

One thing I did notice that the only thing unique the in each row of the result set was a column called 'Position_Number'. So in the dataset properties I thought it would be easy to just place a DISTINCT on column only to find out that's not possible. I tried a host of queries but none of them seem to work.

- Row number seems to not work because it's not supported in Data set properties

  ```
    row_number() over (partition by field1 order by field2)
  ```
- GROUP BY doesn't work

I've tried a bunch of queries from all over similar to this:

```
 SELECT * FROM
vw_InvoiceOilPhyInspectionFees AS G1
JOIN (SELECT  findetail_position, max(vw_invoice_invoicedate) as mostrecent 
     FROM  view_Fees group by  findetail_position) AS G2
 ON G2. findetail_position = G1. findetail_position and g2.mostrecent = g1.vw_invoice_invoicedate
ORDER BY G1. findetail_position
```

TL:DR: What I'm really asking....is there anyway from the SSRS report end of things to basically have  SELECT DISTINCT on one of the result set columns? I feel like i'm in a weird in-between where no solutions works...

Comment: Hi for that exists groups in table and matrix control. Only you need create a table for example this table when is created show a group calling Details open this group using the Arrow and add a Primary group after use the Arrow from the new primary group and add a secondary group if you have 5 columns you will have 5 groups for example 1 primary and 4 secondary. After open this group and add a Column from your dataset this action work like group by if you have any question comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get duplicate rows, you can suppress them by doing a DISTINCT or using a GROUP BY.  In your case, GROUP BY is the way to go.  Technique: GROUP BY the columns that are duplicates and use Max() (or equiv) on the columns that seem to be unique and causing duplicate rows.

For example, for data like this:

```
First   Last        City  Zone
-----  ------  ---------- ----
Joe,   Smith,  Cleveland,   1
Bill,Johnson,    Atlanta,   6
Mike,  Truax,   St.Louis,   1  <-- is this the dupe?
Mike,  Truax,   St.Louis,   2  <-- or is it this one?
Eric,  Jones,   Brussels,   4
```

Use a query like this:

```
SELECT First, Last, City, Max(Zone) AS Zone
FROM thatTable
GROUP BY First, Last, City
```

Yields the same results without duplicate rows

```
First   Last        City  Zone
-----  ------  ---------- ----
Joe,   Smith,  Cleveland,   1
Bill,Johnson,    Atlanta,   6
Mike,  Truax,   St.Louis,   2  <-- after applying a Max() aggregate
Eric,  Jones,   Brussels,   4
```

Of course, it should be pretty obvious that I have over-simplified this a bit.  Specifically, I don't want you to get the impression that Max() on any arbitrary column will always give you what you want.  No sir!  It is just one way of supressing a unique column of a duplicating row.  It might be completely the wrong thing to do under some circumstances.

So please check with your users and confirm that Max or Min (or omitting a column, etc) is the right thing to do.  If not, then find out what they expect to see, once it is "working right". Then apply the appropriate aggregate(s).